# Create multiple dynamic TextView with same style declared in xml

Tags: java, android, textview

I want to create multiple dynamic TextView but I need them to look the same way as one of the TextView that already style in xml. How can I do that?

For example I want all the dynamic created TextView to have same attribute as the main one:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mainTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="14dp"/>
```

Comment: what kind of style ? text style ?

Comment: what have you tried so far ?

Comment: sorry for the confuse. Just edited my question to be more specify

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this by using this:

Take a parent Linearlayout with the orientation vertical

```
LinearLayout parentView= findViewById(R.id.parentView);
```

code to add the views:

```
for(int i = 0; i < /*No of views*/; i++) {
View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.catagoryitem, parentView, false);
parentView.addView(itemView);
}
```

Here `catagoryitem` is the TextView with `style xml` file.

Comment: the answer themes correct, but not complete. Please add a pre-requirement step like *create a layout file with styled TextView*, because it is not clear for some people.